# GetJson does not return json results consistently

Tags: jquery, json, cordova, jquery-mobile

Using latest jquery mobile ("http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js) and jquery (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js) and my pagecreate event works most of the time, however, if I click the back button and then attempt to refresh the page, nothing is being displayed. I can see the request happening using FireBug but I can't see why the json results aren't being set on the page.

Thanks!

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#checkout51", function(event, ui) {
thisPage = $(this);
loadPageContent("checkout51.html", function(data) {
    $(thisPage).prepend(data);
});
});

$(document).on("pageshow", "#checkout51", function(event, ui) {
    $.mobile.loadingMessage = "Please wait - loading coupons ...";
  var couponslist = $('#couponslist');
  $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
  var url = "http://www.test.com/request.php?";
  $.getJSON(url, {
        limit: "100",
    coupon_source : "Checkout51"
    }, function (data) {
            var listContent = "";
            listContent += "<li data-role='list-divider'>Checkout51 Coupons</li>";
    $.each(data, function(index, value){
            listContent += "<li><h2><a class='ui-link-inherit' href='coupondetails.html?id=" + value.coupon_id + "'>" + value.name + "</a></h2></li>";
    });
    $('#couponslist').empty().append(listContent).listview('refresh');
   })
    .error(function() { alert("Error while request processing"); })
    .complete(function() { 
  $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg()
    });
});
```

Using this as the HTML:

```
<div class="fixed-header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-role="header" data-theme="b">
    <a href="#" data-theme="b" class='ui-btn-left' data-icon='arrow-l'>Back</a>
    <h1>Checkout51 Coupons</h1>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
</div>
<div data-role="content" data-theme="c"><br /><ul id="couponslist" data-role="listview" role="listbox"></ul><br /></div>
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer"><div data-role="navbar"><ul><li><a href="index.html" id="menu1" data-role="button" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>     <li><a href="search.html" id="menu2" data-role="button" data-icon="search">Search</a></li><li><a href="subscribe.html" id="menu3" data-role="button" data-icon="info">Subscribe</a></li></ul></div></div><!-- /footer -->
```

I would appreciate any help - this is for a Phonegap application but I would need to see this working consistently using a browser.

Comment: Try `pagebeforeshow` instead of `pagecreate`.

Answer (score 1):

`pagecreate` will fire only one time when the page is first being created. If you want an event to be fired everytime you load the page on browser then you must consider `pageshow`. If you want to load your json request before displaying the page to user then consider using `pagebeforeshow`.

Learn different types of [events available in JQM here](http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/).